# How to make lattice xyplot() grayscale in R?

Tags: r, lattice

What is the simplest way to make just this plot grayscale (or perhaps black and white) rather than the default multi-colour:

```
xyplot(y1 + y2 ~ x, mydata, auto.key=TRUE)
```

I've seen [discussion of creating new graphics devices or changing options for all plots](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-August/207246.html), but is there an option that I can include perhaps in the `xyplot()` function itself that will convert the plot to grayscale?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
library(lattice)
bwtheme <- standard.theme("pdf", color=FALSE)
mydata <- data.frame(y1=rnorm(10), y2=rnorm(10), x=1:10)
xyplot(y1 + y2 ~ x, mydata, auto.key=TRUE, par.settings=bwtheme)
```

For comparison:

[image: comparison of color vs black/white]

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
library(lattice)
mydata <- data.frame(y1=rnorm(10), y2=rnorm(10), x=1:10)
xyplot(y1 + y2 ~ x, mydata, auto.key=TRUE, 
       par.settings=simpleTheme(pch=1:4))
```

[image]