# lattice auto.key - how to adjust lines and points?

Tags: r, graphics, statistics, lattice

When I use `barchart()` and I get something like this (I know the image is not a bar chart but my `auto.key` produces the same legend):

[image: bar-chart]

I would like to fill the points and make them larger or set them to rectangles with the corresponding color.

When I use `densityplot()` and I get something like this:

[image: density-plot]

I would like to make the lines "thicker" if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

daroczig's answer is what I typically do when I face this kind of situation. In general, however, I prefer to use `lattice` default colors instead of specifying my own colors.

You can do that by doing this:

```
lattice.theme <- trellis.par.get()
col <- lattice.theme$superpose.symbol$col
pl <- xyplot(X ~ Y, groups=Z, data=dframe, pch=1:nlevels(dframe$Z),
             type='o', key=list(text=list(levels(dframe$Z)), space='top',
                                points=list(pch=1:nlevels(dframe$Z), col=col),
                                lines=list(col=col),
                                columns=nlevels(dframe$Z)))
```

Answer (score 6):

See `?xyplot`. Some details:

For your first question about changing colors use `col` argument, e.g.

```
barplot(table(mtcars$am, mtcars$gear), col = c("green", "yellow"))
```

[image]

But if you want to deal with a scatterplot instead of barplot (confused here) with modified symbols, then `auto.key` is not on option unfortunately, but something like this would work without problems:

```
xyplot(mtcars$hp ~ mtcars$wt, groups = mtcars$gear, 
        key = list(text = list(as.character(unique(mtcars$gear))), 
                   points = list(pch = 10:12, col = 12:14)), pch = 10:12, col = 12:14)
```

[image]

For your second question use `lwd`:

```
densityplot(mtcars$hp, lwd = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: thx again! i adjusted a few things but basicly this was what i was looking for! kind regards

Answer (score 4):

I just spent a good chunk of time on essentially this same problem. For some reason, the @daroczig style approach wasn't working for changing line types (including for the key) in a densityplot.

In any case, I think the "right" approach is to use `trellis.par.set` along with `auto.key` like so:

```
# Maybe we'll want this later
old.pars <- trellis.par.get()

trellis.par.set(superpose.symbol=list(pch = 10:12, col = 12:14))
xyplot(hp ~ wt, data=mtcars, groups = gear, auto.key=TRUE)

# Optionally put things back how they were
trellis.par.set(old.pars)
```

There's actually less typing this way (especially if you don't count my saving and restoring the original trellis pars), and less redundancy (allowing for DRY coding). Also, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to easily make multiple columns using `key`, but you can add `columns` as one of the elements of the `auto.key` list.

Also, make sure you're changing the right element! For example, if you changed `plot.symbol` (which sure sounds like the right thing), it would not do anything. Generally, for things based on xyplot, I believe `superpose.*` are the right elements to actually modify the symbols, lines, etc.

Comment: yes lattice is very powerfull but to get to know everything i.e. to set everything up takes (like u said) quite some time!

Comment: You can also include the `par.settings` in the call, rather than setting a session default.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9307134/210673

Comment: That is a nicer way to do it if you only want to change parameters for one plot call!